# Why [:1] and [0] do not generate the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do method 1 and method 2 not print the same output?

```
>>> names = ["Apple", "Samsung", ]

# Method 1/Print the first item in names
>>> print(names[:1])
['Apple']

# Method 2/Print the first item in names
>>> print(names[0])
Apple
```

Answer (score 3):

Slicing syntax (Method 1) always produces a new list, even if the new list has only one item.

Indexing (Method 2) produces the item at that position in the iterable.

Comment: I think this is definately adequately explained in the dupe, e.g. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729334/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands The question was not "explain slice notation".  It's not clear the OP knew it was *called* slice notation.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I do know a few things about slicing but actually I have never learned it deeply. Generally, problems like these confuse me so much.

Comment: I didn't downvote the OP but it's clearly a dupe, the answer i linked to even says "indexing gives items, not list" and "Slicing gives lists"